# Import data from excel and use it to create individual files on c drive

Tags: python, excel

Please look at the picture. I have individual acct no in excel Column A that needs to be created as individual files on the c drive. How can I do that without doing it manually?[image]

[image]

Comment: I want to create a batch script in python to do this automatically for 200 acct no and for 3 years. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of python, we could use VBA within excel.

Assuming you wanted to just write out a blank excel file with each one of these names, we could loop over the text in a range, ex:

```vb
Function GetNames(aRange as Range):
    Dim aCell as Range
    # Define ArrayList here
    For Each aCell in aRange:
        ArrayList.add(aCell.Text)
    Next
    Set GetNames = ArrayList
End Function
```

and then loop over each item in that arrayList in a separate function to write them out, ex:

```vb
Sub WriteFiles(ArrayList):
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim name as String

    For Each name in ArrayList:
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add()
        wb.Activate
        wb.SaveAs name
        wb.Close (False)
    Next
End Sub
```